# Image looks like a button only working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is the button i have created using 3 divs. All divs hava images which is used to create a button. This is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/45/).

```
<div class="btncontainer" id="button">
        <a href="#">
            <div id='leftdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png" height="30px" />
            </div>
            <div id='backgrounddiv'>Click Me </div>
            <div id='rightdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png" height="30px" />
            </div>

    </div>
```

I wanted a button appearance and added this code to look like a button.

```
    -webkit-appearance:button;
    -moz-appearance:button;
    -o-appearance:button;
    -ms-appearance:button;
```

This button effect is only working fine in Firefox but is not showing correctly in chrome/IE. Is there any other way to look like a button and works for all browsers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the

```
<button>Some text</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button">
```

element is the most sure way to make something look like a button

EDIT:

To make your button look consistent across Firefox, Chrome, and I/E adding some padding will display the grey "button" effect that you currently only see in Firefox.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/46/)

Comment: i added the padding but the problem with padding is that it is not working fine on IE

Comment: I would highly recommend using the <button></button> approach as it's inline with standards where as these css properties are not. Here's your button using the <button> approach: [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/47/)